# TS - How to catch errors without type assertions in this code

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, which is correct but is tricky to maintain...

```js
interface FuncContainer<F extends (..._: Array<any>) => any> {
  func: F
  args: Parameters<F>
}

const func: FuncContainer<typeof Math.min> = {
  func: Math.min,
  args: [3, 4]
}

console.log(func.func(...func.args))


const funcs: Array<FuncContainer<(..._: Array<any>) => any>> = [
  {
    func: Math.min,
    args: [1, 2]
  } as FuncContainer<typeof Math.min>,
  {
    func: fetch,
    args: ["https://google.com"]
  } as FuncContainer<typeof fetch>
]

console.log(funcs)
```

This compiles without errors. However, he problem is when I have `Array<FuncContainer>`. I want to be able to put different functions with different param signatures in 1 array, so I made the function generic. I also want TS to ensure that the types **within** each array element are consistent. To do that, I have type assertions inside each individual array element, but that is error-prone as there is no warning if someone forgets to add the type assertion to a new element to an `Array<FuncContainer>`. Without it, incorrect types for the args won't be caught.

```js
const funcs2: Array<FuncContainer<(..._: Array<any>) => any>> = [
  {
    func: Math.min,
    args: ["5", "6"] // should error, but doesn't
  }
]
```

Is there a way to annotate the array so that each array element is type-checked for the concrete type within each array position, but doesn't require manual type assertions like this code snippet? Maybe some way with mapped types?

EDIT: changed `unknown` to `any` so it works in the playground

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah thanks for the info. I edited the example to work in the playground by switching to `any` instead of `unknown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is most easily done (from a DevEx perspective) with a function helper:

```typescript
function funcContainer<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: F, args: Parameters<F>) {
    return {func, args};
}

const funcs = [
    funcContainer(Math.min, [1, 2]),
    funcContainer(fetch, ["https://google.com"]),
    funcContainer(Math.min, ["x"]), // <== Error as desired
];

console.log(funcs);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSBhBUCGMwFMBOAPAGKK4AeUuYAJgM6IAUAdK5vgOZ0BcimYATwDaAXQCUiALwA+PoOmMUEXsQA0fTj0QAFdpgC2uKvjolpEgN4AoRLcT4jIfEgtL17LgF8A3Fc9WrCAQ6KGRwCAZJRCEbOyV0MCwcAkYAWUwoAAtmfRx1IQBGdQAmcVVY23iMbDx8RSMITPyAIkyoKAAHHgB6bo44OA4AG1xmIP1msoqwtGrkuvSsnLzo5vJJsXVexEJJKIBRfHw4fD4GGlw6GAcaKxFfQOC4EeYhwcVwujFfIA)

Not only do you get type safety in the args list, you get argument suggestions in any IDE that gets that info from TypeScript (like VS Code):

[image]

Comment: Any way you can add some explanation as to when a helper function is useful? I asked [a question that also required a helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868851/forcing-objects-within-objects-to-be-of-same-type-in-typescript) and I'm trying to understand when we have to resort to helper functions in generic terms but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @JuanMendes - I haven't quite put my finger on it yet either. :-) But I think this is the classic case (in fact, there's probably a duplicate we could point it at) where you want internal consistency within an array/tuple element but diverse types among the elements.

Answer (score 2):

To build on @T.J. Crowder's answer: Here is a solution which only requires a single generic function.

```
function createFuncs<
  F extends ((...args: any[]) => any)[]
>(funcs: [...{ [K in keyof F]: [F[K], Parameters<F[K]>] }]) {
    return funcs;
}

const funcs = createFuncs([
    [Math.min, [1, 2]],
    [fetch, ["https://google.com"]],
    [Math.min, ["x"]], // <== Error as desired
]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQMXBAZwB4AoRRHRNAD2zABMDEAKZgOg4xQHMCAuRBjABPANoBdAJSIAvAD5BIyRJJzmoSP0SiObAN7aA0ohhIA1mmFxgFcQNE5Rh8QBpEABS4YAtmmwpiR2c5cUQAXylEPTJyRHQoEBQkDUIAbhIwkhIIBAIoRBSmGWR0LFx8AmZRGPJRAFksAAs2b1M3UQBGNwAmcVca7WA-CEb2gCJGqCgAB34AejnuODhuABs0NhzvMb6XAfqmlrbtMeod10QFxCIZYoBRFBQ4FEEmejQCGHR6Eil07NycHWbFWK3UFUk6SAA)

Comment: Why not use objects instead of tuples? Still works: https://tsplay.dev/mM1Dlm

Comment: @kelly - yeah, I did not really read the question and only saw Crowder's solution and adapted it.

Comment: Sadly, the DevEx isn't as good -- no argument suggestions. :-( (But it's more concise to use.) Other than that, this is really cool. (I don't see how my answer encourages using tuples over objects, though; I just used the same things -- objects for the func/args pairing, tuples for parameters -- the question did.)